# STM32F0 ADC reads wrong values

Tags: microcontroller, adc, stm32, stm32f0

I am using STM32F030F4P6 MCU for a project. This MCU has no Vref+ pin and using VDDA pin for A/D conversions, PLL etc. While prototyping the circuit that I am going to use on my project, I shorted VDDA and VDD pins together with 10uF and 100nF capacitors to the ground. I am giving exact 3.3V to these pins with an DC power supply.

ADC will be reading voltage with max amplitude of 16.8V. Therefore I've used 10k / 2k voltage divider, to bring this voltage to logic level. Since I will be reading mostly DC values, I've set the sampling time to highest possible which is 239.5 adc clock cycle - 17.1 microseconds.

The problem is values that I read are way different than voltages I measure with multimeter. For example, ADC is reading ~2.8V when I measure 2.87V.

As you know these MCUs have Vref built-in which you can read through ADC_IN17. When I try to use this to calibrate my ADC, this time measured voltage is lower than read voltage. For example, read voltage is 2.8V when I measure 2.72V.

**ADC resolution is 12 bit and ADC accuracy table is shown below.**

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78189/discussion-on-question-by-sener-stm32f0-adc-reads-wrong-values).

Answer (score 1):

For calibrating with internal VREF you would need to post your code.

For the case without calibration it might actually be the input impedance - the MCU ADC has input impedance of around 50k which might be too low in the case of your divider - try buffering the measured voltage and measuring it again.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments the issue seems to be related to the corelation between MOSFET switching time and ADC reading time.

The 100 mV noise is most likely a periodic noise and readings in phase with the noise cannot lead to an average value, it's like averaging sin (t) at 2*pi*n + c  points

Filtering the ADC input might help reduce the corelation if the noise path is not inductive.

If oversampling to a higher rate than switching time is not an option then at least moving the sampling point far from transitory area could help.